# Phonegap: Failed to clean android project

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

After installing camera plugin for Phonegap 3.1.0-0.15.0 it gives following error when I try to compile for Android:

```
[error] An error occurred while building the android project. Buildfile: "path removed by me"\build.xml
ERROR: Failed to clean android project.
```

Error persists after I've removed camera plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to use `ant clean` it appeared that it couldn't modify `bin` folder. I found that it was used by WinRAR o_O. I've killed WinRAR process and problem gone.[image]

Answer (score 5):

I got this error on my CI build, check your cordova/platforms/android/local.properties and ensure that this has the correct path for your android SDK.

Comment: local.properties had correct path to SDK, but as it's auto-generated file I looked into build.xml and there was written that I must use "android update project" and after that problem gone. So, your answer led me to solution :)

Comment: Suddenly I've got this error again and "android update project" doesn't help anymore =/

Comment: After PC restart it compiled again o_O